# How can a processor execute more instructions per period than there are clock cycles?

Tags: cpu, parallel-processing

[This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instructions_per_second) Wikipedia page lists several cases where the instructions per clock cycle per core is greater than 1. How can there be more instructions executed per core per period than there are clock cycles in that same period?

In trying to find an answer to my question I've heard about (if I understand correctly) a single-core parallel executon techniques called out-of-order execution, but it seems to me that since this only seems to apply to the execution stage, the speed should still be constrained by the non-parallelism of the other stages.